# asyncio await not recognized in coroutine

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm working with a simple Python script to get my head wrapped around the `asyncio` module.  I'm going through the documentation which can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-task.html#example-hello-world-coroutine)

However, I noticed that my installation of Python 3 (version 3.5.3, installed on a raspberry pi) does not recognize `async def`, but will recognize `@asyncio.coroutine`.  Thus, my script has changed from the tutorial code to:

```
import asyncio
import datetime

@asyncio.coroutine
def display_date(loop):
    end_time = loop.time() + 5.0
    while True:
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        if (loop.time() + 1.0) >= end_time:
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
# Blocking call which returns when the display_date() coroutine is done
loop.run_until_complete(display_date(loop))
loop.close()
```

However, I'm running into syntax errors at `await asyncio.sleep(1)`.  Is there any reason for this??  It runs fine on my ubuntu machine (which has python 3.5.1)

Comment: You need to use `yield from` when you use the `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator. `await` is only allowed in `async def`

Comment: The problem is that `async def` doesn't seem to be working, even though asyncio is installed (through `python3 -m pip install asyncio`)

Comment: Don’t install asyncio with pip. It’s part of Python’s standard library.

Comment: How are you running your code? Is it possible that you’re using a different version than you think?

Comment: I'm running my code by running `python3 scriptname.py` at the terminal, same as I would any other script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed a re-flash of Raspbian on the belligerent little thing.  It appears to work now.  The odd thing is that the image is the 2019-11-29 version.  Weird.

Answer (score 2):

`await` is allowed inside `async def` function only.

Old-styled coroutines marked by `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator should use `yield from` syntax.

You have Python 3.5.1, so just use new syntax, e.g.:

import asyncio
import datetime

```
async def display_date(loop):
    end_time = loop.time() + 5.0
    while True:
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        if (loop.time() + 1.0) >= end_time:
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
# Blocking call which returns when the display_date() coroutine is done
loop.run_until_complete(display_date(loop))
loop.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`async def` and `await` - are newer syntax that avaliable only since Python 3.5. If you Python doesn't recognize `async def` it won't recognize `await` either.

I hardly believe that some 3.5.3 version doesn't have this syntax implemented for some reason. It's much higher possibility that you're just using older python version. Check it adding to code something like:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

It'll show Python version you're running.

Btw, `asyncio` is standard lib module, you shouldn't install it with `pip` at all.

Comment: output from `print(sys.version)` is:

`>>> print(sys.version)
3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170124]`

Comment: @T.Wallis then you shouldn't have problems with `async def`.

Comment: Exactly, but I found it didn't work anyway.  I performed a reflash of the OS on the RPI and that seemed to do it.